# Take a disk offline from powershell

Tags: powershell

normally to take a disk offline I use the windows disk partition manager. now i would need to do it with a power shell using the drive letter.
I tried with the command:

```
Set-Partition -DriveLetter E -IsOffline $True
```

i get this error from powershell:

```
Set-Partition : The volume still has access path to it.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

I solved it like this:

```
set-disk (get-partition -DriveLetter E | get-disk | select number -ExpandProperty number) -isOffline $true
```